# Product of unipotent subgroups is unipotent

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $H,K$ be two closed normal unipotent subgroups of a linear algebraic group $G$, is their product $HK$ also a unipotent subgroup?

The unipotent radical of $G$ is defined to be the largest connected normal unipotent subgroup of $G$, but I do not know why it exist.  So I hope the above statement to be true.